# 0.9 or 1.1 which is suitable for CBR250RR MC22

Tags: overheating, radiator, heat, cbr250r

I have a CBR250RR MC22 old model gullarm bike, I recently faced issues with overheating of the faulty cap, but some people suggest changing 1.1 and some 0.9 radiator cap, I would like to know the exact cap which I need to change and recommendation for that.

Comment: What does the manual say for that model? The higher pressure cap will cause the boiling point to be higher cf the lower cap.

Comment: Is it overheating or is the cap failing to contain normal pressure?

Comment: @SolarMike since it's an old bike so we don't have manual

Comment: sometimes overheating @GdD

Comment: Just did a google search and there seem to be many possibilities for manuals...

Comment: @SolarMike If you don't know just move away, if I could see or find the manual why would I come here

Comment: I found the manual... as I said with a google search by typing “manual for CBR250RR MC22”  but perhaps my google is different to yours.